# how to move code from master to release branch in git on windows

Tags: git, merge

OK, we have read the git books and probably hundreds or articles, and we are experts are SCCS, VCS, SVN etc but we are really struggling to understand and use git.

We have done all our changes in master.

We now want to copy master to our existing release branch, but have so far failed.

We understand there is no easy way to just merge two branches (one of which has had no changes), and that you cant do it from the master.  We understand you have to checkout the branch you want to merge to (release), merge, then commit.

Our local dev machines have master checked out, and obviously we dont want to touch/break/corrupt/change these, so we clone the project from scratch in a new place (e.g. tmp/merge_area/ourproject

next we go into tmp/merge_area/ourproject in windows explorer and right click on tortoise git-> switch/checkout.

This gives us the option to select "remotes/origin/release", "master" or "remotes/orgigin/master.  Now we are confused:

1. For some reason, there is no local release branch in this list.  Surely, if git clones the entire repo, release branch will also be on my local repo?
2. Under options, "create new branch 'release'" is ticked by default.  This is worrying, as we aleady created a branch release, and we can see this branch when we go to bit bitbucket web UI.  Does this mean that tortoise has a bug, or that when you clone a repo, it doesnt clone any of the branches to your machine except mater?
3. there is a "track" tick box. What is this, and do we want it?

Not really knowing the answer to the above, we went ahead with:

- branch = remotes/origin/release.
- create new branch unticked.
- track ticked

This then gives us the very scarey message:

```
Note: checking out 'remotes/origin/release'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
HEAD is now at b35352e..
```

We are guessing we did it wrong, as this message sounds like we broke it.

What is the correct way using tortoise?

Next we tried the command line, following some examples on stackoverflow.

```
$ git checkout release
$ git merge master
```

So far, so good, but what next?

The example from stack overflow we are following says the next step is

```
$ git push origin release
```

But surely we need to commit the changes from the merge first?  what if we had to fix some merge conflicts, which would be un-committed?

However, when we try this:

```
$ git commit -m "first try"
```

We get the error:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/release' by 24 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Why would committing the changed files locally give an error from the repository?

Comment: When you merge a branch into another, you don't have to commit anything as the merge IS the commit (except in case of conflicts or fast forward)

Comment: The message `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/release' by 24 commits.` is not an error, it is just here to tell you that your local branch is ahead of the remote one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put the modifications that are on `master` in the `release` branch, you should just merge `master` into `release` as follow (in command line) :

(Assuming your branches are up to date locally)

- `git checkout release`
- `git merge master` (this might produce only a fast forward, meaning master and release branch will point to the same commit)
- `git push origin release`

You shouldn't have to clone the repo in another folder, switching branch in Git is something easy.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  what if we had to fix some merge conflicts?  there is no commit step, and if we try to commit, we get the error message above.  When we try your suggestion to push after merge, we get "total 0 (delta 0) reused 0". I assume this meains it didnt work, as there were a lot of changes.

Comment: First if it's a fast forward, there is no conflict possible and ther is not even merge commit created, it is just the branch that points to the same commits as master, think of branch in Git as only pointers to commits.

Comment: Second, if it's a merge without fast forward, there will be a merge commit created, automatically if no conflict. If there are conflicts, you will be in MERGING mode and have opportunity to resolve conflicts and finish by commiting.